# Method setTextColor:range: on NSTextView is ridiculously slow

Tags: regex, macos

I'm creating a simple editor in Mac OS X and I've come to the point where my editor needs to do some highlighting of code, for example, comments.

I am using **Regex** to find all comments, which I initially thought, was slow. Turns out, it does rather amazing job. For example, for 387 comments, regex needs "only" 0.008404 s to find them and returns array of NSRanges.

But here comes disaster. When I try to set different color to my text with method `setTextColor:range:` it completes very slow. It needs additional 9.872964 s (for those 387 comments I mentioned before) and it gets worse really fast when number of comments is increased.

So... Is there any way to do this faster? With `NSAttributedString`s, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really sorry guys, but stackoverflow gave me suggestion on similar question (which I didn't found when I was searching).

It turns out you simply have to tell NSTextViews TextStorage that you will begin doing some editing. And when you finish, you commit those changes. Code looks like:

```
[textView.textStorage beginEditing];
// do some stuff here
[textview.textStorage endEditing];
```

Now I ran code with 456 comments, Regex needed 0.013887 s and coloring 0.215761 s, which is amazing drop!

Anyway, I hope someone will find that useful.